# Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android - how to integrate old Facebook.Dialog with new Session mechanism

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem with integrating the Feed Dialog of the new Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android. The documentation is pretty clear about how to do it, however omitting one very important case, which is only mentioned as if it'll almost never happen.

[Facebook Feed Dialog Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/#step2)

This is the case when the user wants to publish something, but he is not already logged in and does not have Session and Access Token.

The SDK provides a way to set Access Token (and Session as whole) in the old Facebook object, however I cannot find a way to get the Session or Access Token after the user has logged in and posted his feed via the Feed dialog.

So the flow is:

1. User presses the share button.
2. He is not logged in so there is no Session Access Token
3. `facebook.dialog()` is started and the login dialog is presented
4. the user logs in and shares his link
5. he is back to the application, but he still does not have Session Access Token and he is not logged in to facebook, although he logged in before a minute.

My question is, how can I get the access token in step 5 (which is created somewhere for sure) and use it in my program to create a valid SDK 3.0 Session object, so that the user can have valid Session with Access Token after using the facebook dialog?

--- EDIT ---

I just want to clarify that the case is, when the native facebook app is not installed on the phone - therefore a webview dialog is used I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set an opened Session on the Facebook class, dialog() should not prompt the user to log in.

Here is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    boolean pendingShare;
    Session session;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingShare = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("pendingShare");
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, new SessionCallback(), savedInstanceState);
        }

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickShare();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("pendingShare", pendingShare);
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (session != null) {
            session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void onClickShare() {
        pendingShare = true;
        session = new Session(MainActivity.this);
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(MainActivity.this).setCallback(new SessionCallback()));
    }

    private void share(Session session) {
        Facebook facebook = new Facebook(session.getApplicationId());
        facebook.setSession(session);
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", null);
        pendingShare = false;
    }

    class SessionCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened() && pendingShare) {
                share(session);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Saving/restoring "pendingShare" (and session) is useful here because your Activity can be unloaded during login, this remembers to trigger the dialog() call when MainActivity is reloaded.

Comment: The problem is not how to reuse already existing Session by the Facebook class, it's the opposite - if there is no Session and the Facebook class (dialog) create one, how to use it after that with Session. Facebook.getSession() does not work unless there was previously Facebook.setSession() done manually. But this is not the case.

Comment: Yes.  If you call dialog() before logging in, then no token ever comes back to the phone, so that forces the user to type name/password and does not leave the user logged in.  The sample above is intended to show how to create the Session just in time if you don't already have one at the time you want to call dialog().  The user experience is the same or better than what happens if you don't create the Session first.